# how to remove quote from forfiles variables

Tags: windows, variables, command-line, cmd

I need to generate an xml from windows command prompt using the forfiles command.

I'm not so far, but the variable contains quotes and i don't want it ...

Here my current command:

```
%FF_CMD% /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo ^<root^>^<dir^>@fname^</dir^>^</root^>"
```

the result is:

```
<root><dir>"DIRNAME"</dir></root>
```

but i want this:

```
<root><dir>DIRNAME</dir></root>
```

any idea ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create additional batch file, say "echoxml.bat". This will allow to use `~` notation to strip quotes:

```
@echo off
echo ^<root^>^<dir^>%~1^</dir^>^</root^>
```

and then use the batch file in forfiles:

```
%FF_CMD% /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echoxml.bat @fname"
```

EDIT:
Another option would be to change `forfiles` to `for`, or even `for /d` if it is possible (I do not know what arguments you use in `%FF_CMD%`):

```
@echo off
for /d %%A in (*) do echo ^<root^>^<dir^>%%~A^</dir^>^</root^>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i found a workaround .. i moved the value to an attribut like that: <root><dir value="DIRNAME"/></root>

Comment: Epic. I didn't realize %~1 would strip quotes. I'd been using

    set file=%1
    set filetrim=%file:~1,-1%